# My code for a hurricane tracker is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I need to use a txt file to track a hurricane and draw it with turtle on python. This is the code I have but I don't know why it is not working. Can anyone help?

```
def irma():
(t, wn, map_bg_img) = irma_setup()
text = open("irma.csv", "r")
lines = text.readlines()
lines = lines[1:]
t.penup()
category = 0
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.split(",")
    lat = float(line[2])
    lon = float(line[3])
    wind = float(line[4])
    if wind < 74:
        t.color("white")
        t.pensize(5)
    elif 74 <= wind <= 95:
        t.color("blue")
        t.pensize(10)
        category = 1
    elif 96 <= wind <= 110:
        t.color("green")
        t.pensize(15)
        category = 2
    elif 111 <= wind <= 129:
        t.color("yellow")
        t.pensize(20)
        category = 3
    elif 130 <= wind <= 156:
        t.color("orange")
        t.pensize(25)
        category = 4
    else:
        t.color("red")
        t.pensize(30)
        category = 5
    t.goto(lat, lon)
    t.pendown()
    t.write(category)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    irma()
```

Comment: what do you mean by it is not working?

Comment: The turtle won't draw anything

Comment: http://nifty.stanford.edu/2018/ventura-hurricane-tracker/irma-assignment.html

Comment: the details of the project can be found here

Answer (score 0):

Specific issue with your code:

Your indentation is a disaster and keeps your code from working correctly.

You've reversed the mapping of latitude and longitude to X & Y.  Longitude is the *long* way around the Earth so it's the X coordinate; latitude is the Y.

When you write the category number, you do so in the same color that you just drew the fat line, so you can't see it.

This is my rework of your code to fix most of these issues:

```
def irma():
    text = open("irma.csv")
    lines = text.readlines()

    category = 0

    t, wn, map_bg_img = irma_setup()
    t.penup()

    for line in lines[1:]:
        line = line.strip().split(",")
        lat = float(line[2])
        lon = float(line[3])
        wind = float(line[4])

        if wind < 74:
            t.color("white")
            t.pensize(5)
        elif 74 <= wind <= 95:
            t.color("blue")
            t.pensize(10)
            category = 1
        elif 96 <= wind <= 110:
            t.color("green")
            t.pensize(15)
            category = 2
        elif 111 <= wind <= 129:
            t.color("yellow")
            t.pensize(20)
            category = 3
        elif 130 <= wind <= 156:
            t.color("orange")
            t.pensize(25)
            category = 4
        else:
            t.color("red")
            t.pensize(30)
            category = 5

        t.goto(lon, lat)
        t.pendown()
        t.color("black")
        t.write(category)

    wn.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    irma()
```

The labelling of the category still doesn't work properly, but I'll leave that to you to fix.